# put forms in the borders of an html block

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve something like this (Puttings the cercle and triangle in the `borders` of an `html block`).

[image]

**Here's the css of my block:**

```
.block { 
    color: red;
}
.cercle { 
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code

Comment: Can you share your `html` please?

Comment: please add js fiddle link

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use `absolute` positioning, and instead of using `border`s use the `CSS3`'s `transform` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Try this as an example:

```css
.box {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #880015;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  top: -12px;
  right:-2px;
  border: 2px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
.triangle {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  right: -12px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 2px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [article](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/), it explains some of the features you are trying to achieve, but it involves solid images, rather than css only.

As a simpler solution, I suggest you to try with a DIV inside a DIV, and have all the content and the simple border in the inner div, and the custom elements (cercle, triangle) inside the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with an cicle, from here it should be easy enough to add other shapes.

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 25px;
}

.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 275px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/b8dthdwn/3/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some `HTML` code first.

something like:

```
<div class="block">4
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.block { 
    background: red;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 90px;    
}

.circle { 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0.3px;
    left: 170px;  
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #000;
}

.triangle {
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-left:10px solid blue; 
    position:fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 187px;
}
```

You can use `position: fixed` to set the element position with `top, left`. 
You can use `z-index` to make things to display above each other...
see example on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nifurimuwo/edit?html,css,output)